# run npm install on private gitlab project from gitlab-ci

Tags: npm, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a private(with ssh) project in gitlab(that wasn't published to npm)
what is the right way to install this project from gitlab-CI?

I get this error:'Host key verification failed.' from gitlab-ci stdout

Comment: Is the npm project in GitLab the same project running the CI build? Can you please share your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file? What version of GitLab or is this GitLab.com?

Answer (score 0):

If the repo you try to access is not the one the deployment runs...
Add a ssh public-key to your deploy-docker-container via gitlab-ci.yml like this

```
  - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )'
  - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
  - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
  - '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'
  - ssh-add <(echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY")
```

With that you can put your private ssh key into a variable in GitLab Project Configuration.

The public key you place inside the private repo Deploy Keys (you find this in the Repo Settings depending on the GitLab version you have).